# How to send Email using Client Object Model ECMA Script/Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, 2013

I want to send Email using Client Object model JavaScript.. I found Somewhere that it is not possible using Javascript but as I am using NAPA Tool for development in SharePoint 2013 this is the only option I have...

Comment: Last resort would be to make a webservice with an email sending method which you call using AJAX. Is that an option for you?

Comment: if it is supported in NAPA Tool SharePoint 2013 then its OK..